# pagespeed module goes back to default after EasyApache update on cPanel server

Tags: html, css, cpanel, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

On cPanel server, after running update of EasyApache, pagespeed module goes back to default - meaning all changes in pagespeed.conf are been removed and looks like it overwritten with default pagespeed.conf file.
Is it possible to prevent it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this as a custom module to your WHM before you run Easy Apache.

See this link https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Custom+Modules

Comment: Thanks, that is exact way I have added it. First custom module then, easy Apache. It's working fine, but sometimes easy Apache need to be updated and when I run the update with existing custom module it resets pagespeed.conf to default one.